# ¿Cómo saber si mi ciclo while se está efectuando?

Tags: php, jquery

*El ciclo WHILE no parece ejecutarse no sé cómo lo averiguo*

```
<?php 
    include('../configuracion/conexion.php'); 
?>



  <script>
      $('document').ready(function() {

        <?php 
       $consulta = "SELECT idCategoria FROM buscar_categoria";
       $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta)or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");

       $categContador=0;
       while ($paisBuscado = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
          $categContador++;
          $categoria=utf8_encode($paisBuscado['idCategoria']);
    ?>  

       var categoriajs = "<?php echo $categoria ?>";
       var categContadorjs = "<?php echo $categContador ?>";

       $('#categoria').append('<option class="elemento '+categoriajs+'" >'+categoriajs+'</option>');

    <?php  
       }

    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
    $conexion->close();
    ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Porque el codigo no se muestra bien ?

Comment: Escribe el código y ya que esté escrito selecciónalo y pícale Ctrl + K o a los "{}"

Comment: Puedes poner un alert() dentro del while. Si se aparece significa que sí entra, si no pues no entra xd

Comment: En google Chrome: Da click derecho sobretu pagina y seleciona inspeccionar elemento. Esto abrirá los Developer Tools. Seleciona la pestaña de Source, busca tu codigo del scrip donde tienes este while y da un breakpoint con dando click en la linea de coidgo, dentro del bloque while. Si no para es porque no se está cumpliendo la condición.

Comment: @Gamez, puedes revisar [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    include('../configuracion/conexion.php'); 
?>
<script>
  <?php 
    $consulta = "SELECT idCategoria FROM buscar_categoria";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta)or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");

    while ($paisBuscado=$resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {

  ?>
        alert("Mensaje del alert");

  <?php
      }
    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
    $conexion->close();
  ?>

</script>
```

Comment: probe esto  y nada que me muestra el alert

Comment: Correccion asi si se mostro lo que paso es que se me olvido ponerle la extencion pero con el primer pregunta si no me funciona

Comment: Correccion asi si se mostro lo que paso es que se me olvido ponerle la extencion pero con el primer pregunta si no me funciona

Comment: Me Fui al inpector y consola @Aaron Romero; me dice que tengo un error de syntasis dice esto:                                                                                                                     <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: categoria in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\www\wwwclashofclanstrueque\php\selectCategJquery.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />

Comment: Entonces dirígete hacia el archivo **selectCate‌​gJquery.php, línea 19**.  Revisa esa variable que la está recibiendo como __Undefined__

Answer (score 0):

En el código que mostraste nunca cierras la función de jQuery(document). Debiese en cambio ser:

```
<?php 
    include('../configuracion/conexion.php'); 
?>
<script>
    $('document').ready(function() {

      <?php 
      $consulta = "SELECT idCategoria FROM buscar_categoria";
      $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta)or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");

      $categContador=0;
      while ($paisBuscado = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
         $categContador++;
         $categoria=utf8_encode($paisBuscado['idCategoria']);
      ?>  

        var categoriajs = "<?php echo $categoria ?>";
        var categContadorjs = "<?php echo $categContador ?>";

        $('#categoria').append('<option class="elemento '+categoriajs+'" >'+categoriajs+'</option>');

      <?php  
      }

      mysqli_free_result($resultado);
      $conexion->close();
      ?>
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas sencillo es hacer un contador e imprimirlo en tu while:

antes de tu while pones:

```
$k = 0;
```

dentro de tu while pones:

```
echo "un texto para identificar ".$k;
$k++;
```

con esto ya sabras cuantas veces se recorre tu ciclo while y si lo recorre o no.